# Правильная разметка

Tags: html, оптимизация, разметка

Есть маленький блок в котором только 2 элемента, с разными стилями. Как правильнее размечать эти элементы, с помощью простых тегов h и p или делать отдельные div для каждого элемента ?

Answer (score 0):

Если эти два элемента имеют семантическое значение заголовка и абзаца, то лучше использовать соответствующие теги h и p и применять стили с помощью CSS.
Поэтому лучше конечно придерживаться семантики HTML и делать структуру более понятной для поисковых систем и в частности юзеров с ограниченными возможностями.

На удивление в США можно засудить публичную компанию/сайт за то что он не предоставляет нормальную возможность доступа людям с ограниченными возможностями

Comment: А class приписывать h и p, или можно оставить так?